# 2 tags meaning the same (Badge and Badges

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges

There are 2 tags with the same purpose: Badge and Badges. I think badges should be used instead of badge since it includes one or many badges.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the note :)

If the tag is only used once, you can just edit the question that uses it to use the more popular tag instead. I've just done that for this question.

Comment: Wouldn't making synonyms be more future proof?

Comment: You're right. Synonyms must of course be used for tag duplicates which are used regularly. For this one, just removing the tag was plenty good enough and saved some time.